# Filtro de consulta php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

## Estrutura BD

### Empresas

```
 -----------------------------------
 | uid   |   nome    |  endereco   |
 | 1     | empresa01 |  endereço01 |
 | 2     | empresa02 |  endereço02 |
 -----------------------------------
```

### Produtos

```
 -------------------------------------------
 | id |  produto  |  valor | empresa | tags|
 | 1  |  produto1 |   1    |    1    |   a |
 | 2  |  produto1 |   1    |    2    |   a | 
 -------------------------------------------
```

Se o usuário fizer uma busca pelo `"produto1"` ou tag `"a"` vai retornar os produtos das duas empresas. Quero colocar um filtro caso o usuário queira filtrar apenas pelos produtos de uma empresa, a consulta que tentei é essa abaixo mas não funcionou como queria! Quando filtro pela empresa 1 retorna certo mas ao filtrar pela empresa 2 trás as duas empresas.

```
$filtrar = mysql_query("select * from produtos inner join empresas
on  uid = empresa where empresa = '$filtro' and  produto like '%$busca%'
or tags like '%$busca%' ");
```

Objetivo: Pesquisar por `"produto1"` filtrando `empresa = 2` deve retornar apenas o produto da empresa 2`.

Answer (score 1):

O `or` deve ficar dentro de parêntese para que fique isolado das demais instruções:

```
select *
from produtos
inner join empresas
on  uid = empresa
where empresa = '$filtro'
and  (produto like '%$busca%'
or tags like '%$busca%')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$filtrar = mysql_query("select * from produtos inner join empresas
on  uid = empresa where empresa = '$filtro' and  (produto like '%$busca%'
or tags like '%$busca%') ");
```